# Always hide a page from the menu

Tags: plugin-development, menus

I have a page that solely exists to display search results from a different search page. I am creating a plugin and need to make sure when the plugin is activated and pageA and PageB are created pageB doesn't appear in the top-level menu or any menu if possible. Ideas?

Comment: It's possible to do this without any pages at all using rewrite rules

Comment: Have you tried `register_post_type()` for the page you do not want on a menu? Or, are you using a standard page?

Comment: It's currently being created as a page but I COULD create a custom post type and hide it that way. I'm a noob so any advice on best practice is appreciated.

Comment: @TomJNowell Got an example?